# how search algorithm exactly behaves with this function: f(n)=3h(n)

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Imagine I am performing a best-first search based on the function `f(n)=cg(n)+(3-c)h(n)` for selecting the next node to expand. If I use `c=0` I will get `f(n)=3h(n)`. Can I say that with `c=0` the search algorithm behaves exactly like Best first search or greedy best first search?

(I am in doubt between the two. My answer is yes because it just looks ahead and do not consider g(n) and also my feeling is best first search because it overestimate by multiplying by 3 so it is not greedy but I am not sure if I am right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to algorithms like A* which perform a best-first search based on f-cost, where `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)` and the g-cost of a node is the cost to reach that node, while h-cost is the estimated cost to reach the goal.

Dijkstra's algorithm uses `f(n) = g(n)`.

Pure heuristic search or greedy best-first search uses `f(n) = h(n)`.

Your question is what happens if I have:

`f(n) = c*g(n) + (3-c)*h(n)`

When `c = 0` this reduces to:

`f(n) = (3)*h(n)`

The constant of 3 here has no influence on the search order, because all nodes are weighted equally in the same way. So, this is closest to a greedy best-first search.

Comment: what about the case when we have f(n)=g(n)? I tend to say uniform cost search but on the other hand if all edges are 1 then I should consider  BFS or DFS too. what do you choose in this case?

Comment: If all edges are 1, then you have a BFS or a uniform cost search. See the [wikipedia page for uniform cost search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search) for more details.

Comment: Yes I know . I ask this because I am asked to choose the most appropriate search algorithm for this scenario and I think both are appropriate for f(n)=g(n) if the dont mention that all edges are not necessary 1. If you want to answer do you say both are appropriate ?

Comment: @HamedMinaee With f(n)=g(n) you have either Dijkstra's algorithm or Uniform cost search. In the special case where edge costs are uniform, then this is also the same as a BFS.